# $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, prove that $f$ must be either linear or $|f(1)-f(0)|<|f'(t)|$ for some $t\in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

> A function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is such that $f$ is differentiable in it's domain.
> Prove that $f$ , is either linear in $x$ or $$|f(1)-f(0)|<|f'(t)|$$ for some $t\in (0,1)$

**My attempt:**

By **Rolle theorem**, we know that there exist atleast one $t\in (0,1)$ where the equality holds  $$|f(1)-f(0)|=|f'(t)|$$Now , if such equality would have hold for all $t$ in the domain, then clearly $f$ is linear as the slope remains constant.

Now, I try to show that opposite inequality holds false i.e. :

$$f(1)-f(0)>f'(t)$$

By integrating both sides, we get that :
$$\int_0^1f(1)-f(0) \mathrm dt>\int_0^1 f'(t) \mathrm dt$$

$$f(1)-f(0)>f(1)-f(0)$$
which is a contradiction !

**Problems:**

1. I had integrated without taking absolute value as asked in question and hence proof is incomplete.
2. This was the last question in my test and hence was toughest. I believe that my (incomplete) proof is not right in itself because it's too simple.

Can you help me to solve it in correct way ?

Comment: What is $p$ in your definition?

Comment: You seem to be using $p$ and $f$ to mean the same thing?

Comment: @Falcon $p$ represents variable (or a set of) functions which follows the property of elephantsy. And $f$ is one of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First prove that the statement holds for $f(0) = f(1)$ (this should be straightforward). Then assume that $f(1) \neq f(0)$ and set $g(x) = f(x) - (f(1) - f(0))x$, such that $g(1) = g(0)$. Therefore, either $g$ is constant or there is $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that
$$0  < |g'(t_0)| =  |f'(t_0) - (f(1) - f(0))|$$
Can you conclude from there ?

Comment: $f$ is just a differentiable function in a given domain. I'm sorry but I can't see any way to prove that $f(0) = f(1)$ with the given information. Please add it when you wish. Thanks !

Comment: You want to prove the statement for any differentiable function $f$. First you prove the statement in an easier setting, i.e. the set on function satisfying $f(1) = f(0)$ and then you generalize for functions satisfying $f(1) \neq f(0)$.

Comment: It's the same type of argument usually used to prove the Mean value theorem from Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Thanks. The last inequality tells that there must be atleast some $t$ for which the $|f(1)-f(0)|<|f'(t)|$ as well as $|f(1)-f(0)|>|f'(t)|$. And it's sufficient for the original inequality. Right ?

Comment: Did you meant $g(1) = f(0)$ ? How does $g(1) = g(0)$ ?

Comment: $g(1) = f(1) - f(1) + f(0) = f(0)$ and $g(0) = f(0) - (f(1) - f(0)).0 = f(0)$.

Comment: Oops ! I didn't saw the $x$ multiplied.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

The function $f$ is linear if and only if $f(x) = (1-x) f(0) + x f(1)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.  (This says, for instance, that $f(1/4)$ is $1/4$ of the way between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.)

So if $f$ is not linear, there exists an $x$ such that $f(x) \ne (1-x) f(0) + x f(1)$.  Look at what the mean value theorem tells you about $f'(t_1)$ for some $0 < t_1 < x$, and for $f'(t_2)$ for some $x < t_2 < 1$.  Now show that in either case, one of these two cases gives you a $t$ with $|f(1)-f(0)| < |f'(t)|$.

You could break it down according to whether $f(x) < (1-x) f(0) + x f(1)$ or $f(x) > (1-x) f(0) + x f(1)$.  If the absolute values bother you, you can break it down further into the cases $f(1) - f(0) \ge 0$ and $f(1) - f(0) < 0$.

You can see the idea by drawing a picture: sketch a straight line L0 from $(0, f(0))$ to $(1, f(1))$.  If any point $(x, f(x))$ of the graph of $f$ is not on this line, then draw line segments L1, L2 from $(0, f(0))$ to $(x, f(x))$ to $(1, f(1))$.  You'll see that either L1 or L2 must have a greater slope than L0 (and the other one must have a lesser slope), and by the mean value theorem, there is a point where the derivative of $f$ equals this slope.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses the FTC on $f'$.

Do you know Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

> It states that, $$\left|\int u(x)v(x)\mathrm d x\right| \le \left(\int u(x)^2 \mathrm d x\right)^{\frac12}\left(\int v(x)^2 \mathrm d x\right)^{\frac12}$$ With equality only and only if $u = \lambda v$ with $\lambda$ a constant.

If $f$ is not linear then $f'$ is not constant. Let $$M = \sup_{t\in (0, 1)} \left|f'(t)\right|$$

- If $M$ is a maximum $\left(\exists t_0 \in (0, 1),\, M = \left|f'\left(t_0\right)\right|\right)$. Apply Cauchy-Schwarz for $u = 1$ and $v = f'$, So

$$\left|f(1) - f(0)\right| = \left|\int_0^1 f'(x) \mathrm d x\right| < \left(\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\right)^{\frac12} \le \left(f'\left(t_0\right)^2\right)^{\frac12} = \left|f'(t_0)\right|$$

- If $M$ is not a maximum $$\left|f(1) - f(0)\right| \le \int_{0}^1 \left|f'(t)\right|\mathrm d t < M$$ and by the definition of the supremum, there is $t_0\in (0, 1)$, $$\left|f(1) - f(0)\right| < \left|f'\left(t_0\right)\right| < M$$

Comment: Oh that's a beautiful way to prove it, +1!

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding that you use the mean value theorem on the function
$$g(t) = \int_0^t (f'(x))^2dx$$
in the equality in your last line.

Comment: Thanks. But how $ \left(\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\right)^{\frac12} = \left(f'\left(t_0\right)^2\right)^{\frac12}$

Comment: As @Falcon said you use the mean value theorem at that step.

Comment: @Falcon I edit the answer to include that.

Comment: @An_Elephant yes but if you apply the MVT on $g$, you will $g(1) - g(0) = g'(t_0)$ now what are $g(1)$, $g(0)$ and $g'(x)$?

Comment: it should be noted that this solution invokes the FTC, which requires further assumptions on the derivative than in the original question.

Comment: Yes you can say that but also you can avoid it easily let me update the answer.

Comment: @peek-a-boo do you think that the FTC should be invoked?

Comment: it is not necessary to invoke it as shown by the other answers.

Comment: Yes! I am asking after my answer update. Do you think it is still necessary to invoke it?

Comment: well, you are obviously still using it, so I don’t see how your update addresses anything.

Comment: Can you show me in what step I am using it?

Comment: $|f(1)-f(0)|=\left|\int_0^1f’(t)\,dt\right|$. Also, in your second bullet point, how do you know $|f(1)-f(0)|\leq \int_0^1|f’(t)|\,dt$? Keep in mind that integrating derivatives is a **very** subtle matter (you need careful assumptions and also more fancy integration theory to properly deal with this). The other answers are more elementary, relying only on the MVT. Anyway, this is not to say your approach isn’t nice (it’s always nice to see Cauchy-Schwarz in action). One just has to be aware that they’re assuming more than given.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I was not seeing that. We need at least an absolute continuous $f'$.