# $|f(1)−f(0)|<|f′(t)|$ for a continuous and differentiable function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function which is differentiable on $(0,1)$. Prove that either f is a linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ or there exists $t\in(0,1)$ such that $|f(1)−f(0)|<|f′(t)|$.

I think $|f(1)−f(0)|$ is slope of straight line and there is an equality it will give us linear function, but how to approach the problem when f'(t) varies

Comment: Duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699000/f0-1-to-mathbb-r-is-differentiable-prove-that-f-must-be-either-linear-o

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ the mean value theorem implies that $\exists c \in (0,1)$ such that:
$$
f(1)-f(0) = f'(c)
$$
If we were to have equality $\forall c \in (0,1)$ then clearly $f$ is a linear function as the derivative on $(0,1)$ is constant. Otherwise, we would have some value $t$ where equality does not hold. Clearly if $f(1)=f(0)$ the statement holds. Otherwise assume that $f(1)\ne f(0)$, define $g(x)=f(x)-(f(1)-f(0))x$ and see that $g(1)=g(0)$. So either $g$ is constant (making $f$ linear) or $\exists t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
0<g'(t_0)=f'(t_0)-(f(1)-f(0)) \iff f'(t_0)>f(1)-f(0)
$$
for $f(1)-f(0)>0$. Then the inequality follows. If $f(1)-f(0)<0$
then $\exists t_1 \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
0>g'(t_1) \iff f'(t_1)<f(1)-f(0) \iff -f'(t_1)>f(0)-f(1)>0
$$
Either case gives the desired inequality.

(Think about how $g$ has to behave in order to have $g(1)=g(0)$ but still be non-constant).